# how to mimic mouseover listener for xy positions

Tags: snap.svg

I have a snap.svg grid of over 1600 20x20 pixel squares and am I'm trying to find the most efficient way of tracking when a moving point is within each. All I can come up with is looping through all the squares looking for isPointInside like so:

```
for (var t = 0; t < numUnits; t++) {
    var square = squares[t];
    if (Snap.path.isPointInside(square, x, y)) {
        hits[t]++;
        break;
    }
}
```

It sure would be nice if there was a way to create an event listener on each square like mouseover or hover that would do the job instead.

Comment: I think you need to explain the problem a bit further, maybe with a basic testing example on a jsfiddle. It's not clear why you don't put an event listener on each square or the svg or something ? Have you actually tried that ?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. The moving point that I refer to is not a mouse but a series of xy coordinates traversing a grid so a mouseover event won't work. I need to detect how many times each xy hits each grid unit. The only method I know of in snap.svg is isPointInside which, as far as I know, requires me to loop through all the grid squares to see if the point is inside. Here's a jsfiddle i hope will help clarify: http://jsfiddle.net/hfeist/7tm5714n/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend how accurate you want this, and whether sampling from the elements could work.

If so, you could use elementFromPoint

```
   var el = document.elementFromPoint(xArray[j]+8,yArray[j]+8);
   Snap(el).attr({ fill: 'red' });
```

Note, it doesn't quite match up with yours but is close, I'm guessing due to the offset which may need to be factored in (I just tried with 8)

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2bo0mh7h/13/)

Comment: This seems a great solution. Why do you say it's accuracy may be suspect?

Comment: When I compare your method's results with the slow method they are almost identical. Thank you for your help.

Comment: They are not far off, but it may depend if you want 100% accuracy, rather than 99%. I have included an offset, which I'm not quite sure what that is 'exactly'. I'm not sure if for example the width of the lines is taken into account onto each square, and which square it would represent. There are sometimes odd rounding issues in svg/snap.